# Change the disabled color of a button in XAML Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, .net-4.5

I want to be able to change the background color of a button in XAML when it's disabled but I don't know what to override.

Anybody know what I need to do?

I'm create a Windows 8 store app using XAML and C# 4.5.

My current button style is as follows:

```
        <Style x:Key="MySaveButtonStyle"
               TargetType="ButtonBase">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                    Value="Segoe UI Symbol" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="36" />
            <Setter Property="Content"
                    Value="&#xE105;" />
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="70" />
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{StaticResource ButtonForegroudBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="White" />
        </Style>
```

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override the Default ControlTemplate of the Button.

To do this: Right Click the button in Designer View - Edit Template - Edit a Copy

then Visual Studio creates the default Template for you.

In the Template Code there is a VisualStateManager Section with groups and states.

And one of them is

```
 <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
//Change to your demands 
</VisualState>
```

Here you can change it to anything what you want to do when a control is Disabled.